# Floating inside an absolute-positioned div, placed inside a relative positioned element

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, css-position

I'm creating a pure-CSS hover dropdown menu, based on a very basic idea idea.

The HTML:

```
<ul id="top">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">This one has submenu</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>...</ul>
    <div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
div.submenu { 
  display: none; 
  position: absolute;
}
ul#top > li:hover div.submenu { display:block; }
```

As far as I know, this is the bare minimum to get the idea working.
The problem is I want the submenu to be **multi-column**, without actually using CSS3 multiple columns.

So I decided to break my submenu into multiple lists and have them `float: left` like this:

```
<ul id="top">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">This one has submenu</a>
    <div class="submenu">
      <ul>...</ul>
      <ul>...</ul>
      <ul>...</ul>
    <div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

...and the CSS:

```
div.submenu ul { float:left; }
```

This worked well until the point when I got a pretty big submenu in the last main menu item, producing a result like this:

[image]
The problem is it is **unacceptable to have the submenu fall outside the container**. I decided to mark the second half of the main menu items as `class="right"`, and **align the submenu's right border to the parent item's right border**.

```
li.right div.submenu { right: 0; }
/* this placed the submenu to the right of the entire page;
it needs a positioning context: */

ul#top li { position:relative; }
```

That last line causes the `<ul>`'s to stop floating and just get stacked on top of each other.

[image]

Is there a way to *keep them floating without setting the* `<div class="submenu">` *to a fixed width*?

Interactive demo: http://codepen.io/oli-g-sk/pen/ociet

**Edit:** if this helps somehow, it **is** allowed to set the submenu list items `.submenu > ul > li` to a fixed width. In fact I'm already doing it in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `float:left` from `div.submenu ul` and add these two rules:

```css
div.submenu {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.submenu ul {
    /* float:left; <-- remove this */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ApxFd

Comment: I knew there IS some magic trick. Even though it makes sense now, I would never have thought of that. Thank you! :)